# Using jquery ajax to call Microsoft Graph API and officeLocation return null

Tags: jquery, microsoft-graph-api

I have a trouble when using Microsoft Graph API. I'm using `jQuery.ajax()` to call `/users` and filter with some properties including `officeLocation`. Most of the time when I run it in a SharePoint Online it returns `null` for `officeLocation`.

Scopes: `openid` `User.ReadBasic.All` `People.Read` `Calendars.ReadWrite`

Here is my code:

```
function getLocationListByType(type, callback) {
    getAccessToken(function (accessToken) {
        if (accessToken) {
            type = handleEscapeParam(type);

            if (type == 'Room') {
                type = 'room';
            } else {
                type = 'equipment';
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' +
                        sessionStorage.accessToken);
                },
                url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=surname eq '" +
                    type + "'&$select=id,displayName,mail,officeLocation&$top=999",
                success: function (res) {
                    callback(restructuringData(res.value));
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    callback(error);
                }
            });
        } else {
            var error = {
                responseText: 'Could not retrieve access token'
            };
            callback(null, error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What scopes have you requested in your token?

Comment: Thank god you are here Marc. My full scope: "openid User.ReadBasic.All People.Read Calendars.ReadWrite"

Comment: Well written first question Ali256. Welcome to StackOverflow (+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're requesting the `User.ReadBasic.All` scope which only provides access to a very limited set of properties:

- `id`
- `displayName`
- `givenName`
- `mail`
- `surname`
- `userPrincipalName`
- `photo`

In order to retrieve `officeLocation` you will need to request the `User.Read.All` scope. This does require higher privileges however so you'll also need to receive [Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) from a Global Administrator in the tenant.

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur, thank you so much for your time and for your answer. Actually i tried with all scopes of `/users` but `officeLoaction` still is `null`. However i will try again when i get back to office. Thank you again.

Comment: Dear @MarcLaFleur, your answer is helpful, i did get the value of `officeLocation` with `User.Read.All` scope. Thank you.